# Is the SN1 reactions stereospecific or stereoselective?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

In the S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction, the product show retention and inversion. Since one of them is major unless it forms a racemic mixture, does it mean that the S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction is stereospecific?

Comment: products of purely SN1 reactions are racemic in nature, There is no stereospecificity.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](https://vrchemistry.chem.ox.ac.uk/iom/sn1/default.htm)

> The S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction - A Nucleophilic Substitution in which the Rate Determining Step involves 1 component.

-S<sub>N</sub>1 reactions are unimolecular, proceeding through an intermediate carbocation.

-S<sub>N</sub>1 reactions give racemization of stereochemistry at the reaction centre.

-The first step is slower and therefore determines the rate.

-Neighbouring group participation is S<sub>N</sub>1 reactions can be important.